# puppet onlyif specified nodes

Tags: linux, puppet

I'm trying to write a puppet template. I have a puppet-master and a few puppet-agents and they all must be divided. I think it's good to do this by the node's hostname.
But when I tried to do this I've encountered an error

`"puppet-agent[169037]: (/Stage[main]//Exec[adduser]) Could not evaluate: Could not find command 'ru1'"`

see code below

```
exec { 'adduser': 
        command => 'sudo adduser -m -p pawSfQewWrUAA test -G wheel',
        path => [ '/bin','/usr/bin' ],
        onlyif => "$hostname == ru1"
}
```

I need to specify this task for only one node with the hostname ru1.
So have can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: FWIW - wouldn't it be easier to use the `user` type?

Answer (score 7):

Wouldn't this be quite a lot more easier and sensible?

```
case $hostname {
    ru1: user {
             ensure => 'present',
             name => 'test',
             gid => 'wheel',
             password => 'pawSfQewWrUAA',
             otherparametersgohere,
             }
}
```

Code syntax might not be perfect, since this was just out of my head, not checking the syntax or testing this in any way. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Only is expecting a shell command to be executed, not a condition like what you have, which should be a case instead.

Comment: Yes, should working. Thank you all. Ill check it later